# Server Side Events / Chrome Errors

Tags: google-chrome, nginx, eventsource

I'm experiencing a console error on Chrome & Firefox after every few minutes but events are still coming through - this continues on for a while until eventually Chrome logs a 520 error & Firefox 'can't establish a connection to the server' resulting in the eventsource breaking completely.

I tested this locally and no issues at all in either browser. The difference in our production environment is that we are behind an nginx proxy and CloudFlare security.

These are the headers I'm using in the backend:

```
  'Connection': 'keep-alive',
  'Content-Type': 'text/event-stream',
  'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
  'X-Accel-Buffering': 'no'
```

This is the code in the backend (node JS)

```
res.writeHead(200, headers);
res.setTimeout(1000 * 60 * 120)
res.flushHeaders()
req.on('close', () => {      
  res.end()
})
res.on('timeout', () => res.end())
```

And these are the nginx configurations I have tried:

```
proxy_set_header Connection '';
proxy_http_version 1.1;
chunked_transfer_encoding off;
proxy_buffering off;
proxy_cache off;
http2_max_field_size 64k;
http2_max_header_size 512k;
proxy_read_timeout 12h;
```

Front-end code

```
 let source = new EventSource('/events')
 source.onerror = (e) => console.log(e)
 source.onmessage = (msg) => console.log(msg)
```

Chrome Console:
[image]

Appreciate any advice. Thanks

Firefox console:
[image]

Comment: 520 is a [cloudflare specific error](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/115003011431#520error), firefox and chrome handle it differently since it isn't exactly standard. Also I see http2, cloudflare has some funny http2 support, so might need to check cloudflare http2 settings and make sure that the http version between cloudflare and nginx is understood and supported. Meaning at what point is it http1 and what point https2, sometimes it can only be downgraded, sometimes upgraded

Answer (score 0):

I've went through this myself and it turned out to be caused by CloudFlare proxy. Seems CloudFlare will terminate the connection after some time.

To solve this simply turn off the CloudFlare proxy as described here: https://docs.readme.com/docs/turn-off-cloudflare-proxy

Make sure to create a subdomain so you don't disable proxying for your entire website.